# Download the .mp3 file from the bot by python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to send an MP3 file to Telegram bot and download it through python-telegram-bot, but I get an error.

CODE:

```
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes, MessageHandler, filters

TOKEN: Final = '....'

async def music_handler(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    fileName = update.message.document.file_name
    new_file = await update.message.effective_attachment.get_file()
    await new_file.download_to_drive(fileName)
    await update.message.reply_text(f"{fileName} saved successfully")

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.ALL, music_handler))

    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)
```

Unfortunately, I checked the python-telegram-bot documentation, but I didn't find anything. I just want to download the file. I use the latest version of python-telegram-bot. Please if anyone can help me. Thankful.

Error:

```
return await self.callback(update, context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\telegram\admin.py", line 11, in music_handler
fileName = update.message.document.file_name
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_name'
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting to the question?

Comment: return await self.callback(update, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Desktop\telegram\admin.py", line 11, in music_handler
    fileName = update.message.document.file_name
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_name'

Comment: Please don't put that into the comments and edit the original question instead

Answer (score 0):

[`filters.ALL`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.ALL) catches *any* incoming message, i.e. also those messages with [`Message.document`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.document) being `None`. You can use [`filters.Document.ALL`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Document.ALL) to catch only messages with `Message.document` being set.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.